# Why is there a sharp increase in the difficulty curve at Pulse?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

I spent my weekend playing through Final Fantasy 13 and managed to get up to Pulse late afternoon Sunday.

I haven't been avoiding any encounters the entire way through, I've used good strategies to get good weapon upgrades (pouring 36 Sturdy Bones and then anywhere between 20 and 50 Turbojets once the weapon has reached x3 EXP BONUS). My characters up until now have shredded anything they come up against including an easy Barthandelus battle.

I made my way through the Ark with ease and defeated Bahamut and afterwards made my way to Pulse.

OK so now I'm here on Pulse and have defeated Hope's Eidolon. I've reached the huge open area where you have access to Cie'th stone quests and suddenly I feel like I've missed something major or should have done a tonne of farming beforehand.

There are a scarce few enemies here I can actually defeat. The King Behemoth gets me once it stands up and starts using Thundaga to kill my party in two strikes. The huge turtle things - I don't even understand how these could possibly be beaten at all. The wolves in groups larger than 3 are too tricky to bother. The bird type enemies use an attack called "Feeding Stoop" or similar that kills a party member instantly. Etc etc.

Is this a point in the game where I need to venture around these enemy types and slowly (very slowly) work my characters up through fighting the smaller enemies like Goblins and other smaller creatures? Or have I accidentally bypassed a huge portion of the game somewhere and am ridiculously underpowered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are hugely underpowered for the majority of the enemies on Pulse, since Pulse is the end game location - your characters have access to that area and all the missions after the main story of the game is completed.

At this point, you should just finish the missions you need to move the story forward and don't worry about any of the enemies that are too difficult to defeat.  Once you are done the story, you will be able to defeat most of the enemies in Pulse and you can spend time grinding in order to defeat them all (and finish all the missions).

Comment: Ah! So you can return afterwards? That makes a little more sense. So really it's just a dodgefest from here until I make my way to the next area?

Comment: Somewhat - it's been awhile since I played, but I believe that if you follow the story, it avoids the majority of the bigger enemies and leads you along a path of enemies that are appropriate for your current level.

Comment: And the [requisite link to an older question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/in-final-fantasy-13-can-you-get-back-to-pulse-after-taking-the-ship-back-to-coc) regarding whether you can return or not.

Answer (score 4):

Gran Pulse is a little different to the other areas of the game, in that your stats start rising much quicker and it's fairly easy to get yourself caught up in a fight you can't really win.

Pushing forward can cause problems, because there's quite a few chokepoints where you'll be required to fight very strong enemies. While FF13's battle system is much more forgiving of underpowered characters than other Final Fantasy games, that doesn't mean these fights are going to be easy or quick.

Your best bet is to follow the Cie'th stones; not only are these enemies much easier to manage, but they'll lead you back through the pass you entered the main area into another, smaller area with easier enemies. There's an optional boss fight at the end which will wake up the teleport Cie'th stones, and give you access to a new store.

Comment: Are all of the missions achievable at this point in the game or should I wait until I return as mentioned in the previous answer?

Comment: Depends on how patient you are; you can probably beat the boss from Cie'th Mission 7 if you're patient enough, but many of the teleport ones will be too tricky. The point is more that you'll gain enough CP to make your trip across the rest of Gran Pulse significantly less perilous. There's also a couple of story events you won't otherwise see.

Comment: Seems like I'll need to max out at least two roles per character to get to a point where the area becomes reasonably survivable.. Problem there is that stage 8 takes 4000/6000 CP per node so it will take many hours.

Comment: You shouldn't need that much; if you're getting stuck on a Gran Pulse fight, go somewhere else or try and go around.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep following the waypoint arrow. Once you get underground, you can farm the pulse automata for XP and pretty valuable drops. Valuable in the sense that they are good upgrade material.

Answer (score 0):

It's common once you get here to be rather weak towards most enemies. For me personally I've always spent many many hours on gran pulse before moving on. By the time I left even a king behemoth wasn't that major of a problem, if you take the time then by the next chapter you won't be having too many problems at all. It's all on your play style and how much your willing to put forth.

Comment: The cool thing with spending lots of time on Pulse is that when you complete the Bakhti parts quest, you get a bigger reward if you've taken at least 10000 steps on the planet.

Answer (score 0):

On Gran pulse do missions 1 through 28 on order. This will take you through everything and make you an appropriate level to finish the game. If you want at the start of chapter 13 you can come back and farm until you're max crystarium with starting classes by doing missions (for me this was about up to mission 38). Then I'd recommend finishing the game, coming back if desired and doing the rest of the missions